# Graphical functions in C

Tags: c, turbo-c, bgi

Why I see nothing when I run my code ?
I use DOSBox.

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <bios.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int gdriver = DETECT,gmode = 0;
    initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode,"C:\\TC\\BGI");
    struct time t;
    moveto(5,10);
    outtext("Hello");
    moveto(6,11);
    outtext("World**strong text**");
    moveto(1,24);
    outtext("Press: 1-About_Author, 2-Current_Time,ESC to EXIT");
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the result with `graphresult()`. It was always a pain to make Turbo C understand where its own libraries were located. IIRC you could solve such problems by adding "egavga.bgi" to your project.

Comment: How to do it? Should I use #include "egavga.bgi" ?

Comment: I have changed int gdriver = 9,gmode = 0;
9 - VGA, 0 - VGA
but, output is empty :(

Comment: It is not an include file, it is a binary. Try adding it to your project through Project -> Add item.

Comment: I have done it, but when I am compiling files I am catching more errors in
"egavga.bgi". Any ideas ?

Comment: Dropping the DOS junk in favour of a modern graphics library sounds like the most feasible solution.

Comment: Thank's for your good advice. I will use WinBGIm from https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/dev-c++/

Comment: That's not modern though... Dev C++ is in fact no longer maintained. I was rather thinking about things like OpenGL, DirectX, QT, etc etc.

Comment: Will the Visual Studio helps me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right. The problem is with the path you are giving to search for the display driver files `"C:\\TC\\BGI"`. This generally happen because the `tc` is not root of the mounted drive or the `.exe` file path you are using is not `c:\\TC`. Replace the path with `"..//bgi"`. This will redirect from `bin`(**the current working directory**) to bgi.