# Success compiling but no display, setting bkcolor

Tags: c++, turbo-c, bgi

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\\TURBOC3\\");
    setbkcolor(CYAN);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

The compiling was successful and tried running it, but the result was I see no display for my code It's just a blink of screen and gone back to the console.

[image]

Comment: #rip turbo c++ switch to gcc/g++ (codeblocks/visual studio//devc++)

Comment: add second getch maybe, sometimes it needs two, three. depends on OS

Comment: @tohaz done but nothing change.

Comment: @udit043 I'm using turbo c++ cause this is what we're using in our school.

Comment: Request your teacher to use devc++/codeblocks bcz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-should-i-not-use-turbo-c

Comment: lets change school

Comment: Maybe you need `clrscr()` to clear the screen and fill it with new color.

Comment: @alkhemet - There is a problem in that those of us who once used Turbo-C++ stopped doing that about 25 years ago. So we simply don't remember enough to help you with these problems. The second problem is that you now learn things that you will have no use for outside school. Sad!

Comment: PS: In the good days of Borland C++ (this IDE) there was no Internet and the compiler includes good Help system. Read it, read books. No need to ask for every little  step here - otherwise you will not learn to program.

Comment: i get graphics not initialized error. just put your getch after each line, its a simpliest debug method we used back then

Comment: @tohaz No, please! Even Turbo C++ seems to have breakpoints. https://www.wikihow.com/Debug-a-C%2B%2B-Program

Comment: @BoPersson It still has it use depends on the person on how he can apply it.  It'll just be my first PL to help me understand how to code. Getting my grades high and preparing for other PL that I want to learn. I think It'll have no big difference on using other IDE for C++.

Comment: @alkhemet Yes, to some extent. However, please keep in mind that you are learning a non-standard dialect of the C++ language together with non-standard libraries (like `graphics.h` aka [BGI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bgi/info)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphical functions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219457/graphical-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

you need to point initgraph to bgi subfolder of turboc3

```
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code may compile successfully but your code is having a runtime problem. Just add these line first below the line you initialized your graphics.

```
int errorcode = graphresult();

if (errorcode != grOk) {  /* an error occurred */
  printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));
  printf("Press any key to halt:");

  getch();
  exit(1);   /* terminate with an error code(requires process.h) */
}
```

Through these lines runtime problems of graphics can be detected. Its just a safety method for avoid errors and system crash. Well these lines will tell you that they cannot find the file `VGAEGA.bgi` file. That's generally the default drivers of graphics.

The reason the file is not found is your path `c:\\TURBOC3\\`. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219457/graphical-functions-in-c/46140145#46140145) post for avoiding the errors.